# SQL Server merge replication and vertical partitioning on some tables after scripting of a publication

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, merge-replication

We have a database that we changed during the time in terms of adding/removing articles, columns to replication articles in a publication. Now when we script out that publication we have lines of code that are telling us that vertical partitioning is in question, like this:

```
exec sp_addmergearticle @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @type = N'table', @description = N'', @creation_script = N'', @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000C034FD1, @identityrangemanagementoption = N'none', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @force_reinit_subscription = 1, @column_tracking = N'false', @subset_filterclause = N'', @vertical_partition = N'true', @verify_resolver_signature = 1, @allow_interactive_resolver = N'false', @fast_multicol_updateproc = N'true', @check_permissions = 0, @subscriber_upload_options = 0, @delete_tracking = N'true', @compensate_for_errors = N'false', @stream_blob_columns = N'true', @partition_options = 0
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'LOG_DATE', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'LOG_USER', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'COLUMN_NAME', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'ROW_ID', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'ROW_DELETED_VALUE', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'STATEMENT', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'PROCESSED', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'BATCH_ID', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'SERVER_NAME', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'APP_NAME', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'rowguid', @operation = N'add', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
GO
```

Note here that @vertical_partition = N'true' and also note that we never do any vertical partition at least not intentionally.

Now the real issue here is when there are some computed columns in a table, and those computed columns are at the beginning of the table/article script (that includes vertical partitioning) processing will skip those columns! Because those columns are added to the replication article before their referenced column and thus they will break that `sp_mergearticlecolumn` statement. To avoid this (without checking every statement among 400) is to replace `@vertical_partition = N'true'` with `@vertical_partition = N'false'` and then run the whole thing. And this will work. BUT when you try to script out the whole thing those vertical partitioning statements will come again! WHY?

So again:

1. what vertical partitioning actually means and why does SQL Server add it to
   the replication scripts?
2. how to check if a table is vertically partitioned?

Thanks
Dejan

**UPDATE**

I am digging on this now deeper, and started looking on tables themselves and noticed folowing:

Some tables were missing some indexes, like 1,2,3,5 -> where column at index 4 was probably deleted at a point of time. Could that cause this? Could that cause the publication scripting procedure to think that this is a partitioned table? If so then the Microsoft developers didn't finish this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "what vertical partitioning actually means"

Vertical partitioning for a table article means that only specific columns and not all columns of the table are published.

> why does SQL Server add it to the replication scripts

Most likely there are columns which are deselected/dropped from the article/table.
Could you check in the article properties if there are columns which are deselected/not published?

Script wise, you could achieve the same by creating an article with @vertical_partition = N'false' and later @operation = N'drop' a column

```
--no vertical partitioning, all columns of the table are published
exec sp_addmergearticle @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @type = N'table', 
@description = N'', @creation_script = N'', @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000C034FD1, @identityrangemanagementoption = N'none', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @force_reinit_subscription = 1, @column_tracking = N'false', @subset_filterclause = N'', 
@vertical_partition = N'false', @verify_resolver_signature = 1, @allow_interactive_resolver = N'false', @fast_multicol_updateproc = N'true', @check_permissions = 0, @subscriber_upload_options = 0, @delete_tracking = N'true', @compensate_for_errors = N'false', @stream_blob_columns = N'true', @partition_options = 0;

--drop/deselect one column from the article
exec sp_mergearticlecolumn @publication = N'secspe_pub', @article = N'Customer_DELETE_LOG', @column = N'LOG_USER', @operation = N'drop', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1;
GO

--if you script the publication anew, it will have article @vertical_partition = N'true' and all columns @operation = N'add' except for the LOG_USER column (which is excluded from publication and does not appear in the script at all)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer, all columns were replicated in all cases, I've created a script then replaced all vertical_partition = N'true' with vertical_partition = N'false' and run it again and that way created publication (although leaving exec sp_mergearticlecolumn... which produce some warnings that columns already exists). Now when I script that way created publication script comes out again with some vertically partitioned tables, and for me this is very strange. Your thoughts?

Comment: well, in that case, besides the warning (the column already exists in the  VERTICAL PARTITION ), sp_mergearticlecolumn of an existing column changes the article/table to a "partitioned" one. I guess it is a side effect.

Comment: which is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-mergearticlecolumn-transact-sql
: Partitions a merge publication vertically. This stored procedure is executed at the Publisher on the publication database.

Comment: Ok, then I will drop subscription, create publication script, drop publication, fix the script, execute the script again so we will see. To much effort for nothing I think

Comment: indeed. The table is marked as  vertically partitioned but all columns are published.

Comment: once again thanks for your support, I appreciate that!